# Do I need to allow only https in my backend server ? [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, http, https

I have nodejs backend server which runs in port 5000. Currently it supports both http and https requests.

For me its not a problem because my client applications (frontend applications) uses https requests always. But someone else can send http request using (postman) like apps any time.

But I want to know is this secure ? or do I need to convert each http request to https ? If yes how ?

**Edit 1 ->**

If I need to redirect I can use below code inside server.js,

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.header('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https')
      res.redirect(`https://${req.header('host')}${req.url}`)
    else next()
  })
}
```

But if I use this hacker can send `x-forwarded-proto` as `https` but the url as `http` , in that case also response will be http.

So what would be the best way to redirect http to https ?

Comment: "*But someone else can send http request using (postman) like apps any time.*" so what? If they want to use unsecured traffic, I'm not sure why that's a problem.

Comment: @VLAZ okay got it, Thanks.

Comment: It's a good idea to set up your `http` endpoint to automatically redirect to `https`. There is a risk, unlike @VLAZ thinks, because if you have `http` available bad actors can trick users to use that instead.

Comment: @Evert Thanks for your suggestion. Yes that is possible. If I redirect http request based on 'x-forwarded-proto' header , will this be enough ?

Comment: @Evert I have edited the question (Edit 1).

Comment: @JohnStuart the answer to that is dependent on your server. `X-Forwarded-Proto` suggests you have something sitting in front of your node.js service, so it's easier to handle it there than in Node.js itself.